# Javascript - order of code being executed?

Tags: javascript

I wrote the functions below but their outputs are slightly different. How come the `join()` is not executed in the first example?

```
function dice(number) {
  let results = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    results.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 1)) + 1);
  }
  results.join(", ");
  return `Rolled ${number} dice: ${results}`;
}

//example output: Rolled 3 dice: 5,2,1
```

But when I do this...the `join()` is executed:

```
function dice(number) {
  let results = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    results.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 1)) + 1);
  }
  return `Rolled ${number} dice: ${results.join(", ")}`;
}

//example output: Rolled 3 dice: 5, 2, 1
```

Can someone explains to me why this is happening? Are there any other scenarios where I have to watch out for the "order" of how the code gets executed?

Comment: join is called in the first one, it does not magically change results. Read the description: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: nothing to do with 'order' - it is to do with the fact that you do nothing with the result of calling `results.join`

Answer (score 3):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

> The join() method joins all elements of an array (or an array-like object) into a string and returns this string.

You have to assign that to `result`:

`results = results.join(", ");`

```js
function dice(number) {
  let results = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    results.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 1)) + 1);
  }
  results = results.join(", ");
  return `Rolled ${number} dice: ${results}`;
}

var res = dice(5);
console.log(res)
```